# Distribution groups with Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm just starting with MS Graph and I basically need to get into context. I have a pretty simple task to get Office365 user's Distribution Groups (his own) **and edit** them: add/remove members.

I've watched videos on MS Graph and not sure if it's possible with the Graph. I've done such things in the past but it was LDAP all over. So I wonder if there's a new world out there ;)

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Have looked at any resources? A quick search for "Microsoft Graph" results in the main site: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/ which contains good intro/context info, tutorials, get started guides and the API reference, including to Groups, how to query, create and edit them.

Comment: Man, sometimes you have to decide quickly, having a pile of other tasks to finish. And this topic requires at least a day to dive into. So that's why I asked. Now, thank you for an answer, I now need to find out from a client if he wants to use this ability (with Office365) or to go with LDAP route. At least I know now there's a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to query and update O365 distribution groups (aka Unified Groups) in Microsoft Graph.

To query for unified groups

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```

And once you get the ID (GUID) for the group, you can then update the group as follows:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupId>
Content-type: application/json
{
  description: "My updated description"
}
```

**NOTE:** You can also query distribution groups synced from on-prem, but you can't update those as they are mastered on-prem. To query those replace the filter with securityEnabled eq false and ignore those that have the Unified type.

Check out the following resources for more info:

- Getting started with the Microsoft Graph in .Net: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/aspnetmvc
- Get Group: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_get
- Update Group: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_update

Comment: ok, so when they're synced from on-prem (my client's case), no way to add/remove members to the group. is that correct? in this case I won't be using Graph then. LDAP it up my ass :)